# Integrating with SAML in onelogin

Tags: php, onelogin

I'm trying to understand SAML and building a simple PHP app that will talk to [a docker image of a SAML IDP](https://hub.docker.com/r/kristophjunge/test-saml-idp/). I set that up an got it running on port 8081.

I setup the IDP config:

```
'idp' => [
    // Identifier of the IdP entity  (must be a URI)
    'entityId' => 'app.example.com',
    // SSO endpoint info of the IdP. (Authentication Request protocol)
    'singleSignOnService' => [
    // URL Target of the IdP where the Authentication Request Message
    // will be sent.
    'url' => 'http://localhost:8081/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php',
```

I'm unsure what to put in the SP config for the URL value though:

```
'sp' => [
    // Identifier of the SP entity  (must be a URI)
    'entityId' => 'http://authproxy.example.com',
    // Specifies info about where and how the <AuthnResponse> message MUST be
    // returned to the requester, in this case our SP.
    'assertionConsumerService' => [
        // URL Location where the <Response> from the IdP will be returned
        'url' => '',
```

Do I have to write that endpoint myself? If so what does it have to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [typical workflow](http://dulanja.blogspot.com/2014/07/dissecting-saml-spec-validation-of.html) in a Service Provider (SP) initiated SSO workflow is:

1. SP redirects to IdP for authentication with an `AuthnRequest`,
2. IdP authenticates and authorizes,
3. IdP redirects back to the SP-specific Assertion Consumer Service (ACS) with the result.

The Authentication Request (`AuthnRequest`) may include the ACS URL, or it may be hard-coded as part of a static setup (as is seen in your example).

Yes, the SP provides this URL. If you want to roll your own, then you might consider using [OpenSAML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16731934/2908724) generally, or a platform specific package like [OneLogin for PHP](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml). Otherwise, if you are using a SP service, then that service provides a well-known end-point. (For example, [ADFS provides `/adfs/ls`](https://serverfault.com/a/419010/204816).)

Comment: the php-saml repository contains a demo app (https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/tree/master/demo1). Use it to learn how SAML works. The demo1 app is described here:
https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml#demo1